# pandas read_csv - Skipping every other row starting from a certain row

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a huge .csv file (over 1 million rows), that I am trying to parse using the pandas read_csv function. The file is very large because it is measurement data from a sensor with very high sampling rate, and I want to take downsampled segments from it. I tried implementing it with a lambda function and the `skiprows` and `nrows` parameter. What my code currently does is, it just reads the same segment over and over again.

```
segment_amt = 20 # How many segments we want from a individual measurement file
segment_length = 5 # Segment length in seconds
segment_length_idx = fs * segment_length # Segmenth length in indices
segment_skip_length = 10 # How many seconds between segments
segment_skip_idx = fs * segment_skip_length # The amount of indices to skip between each segment
downsampling = 2 # Factor of downsampling

idx = start_idx
for i in range(segment_amt):

    cond = lambda x: (x+idx) % downsampling != 0
    data = pd.read_csv(filename, skiprows=cond, nrows = segment_length_idx/downsampling,
           usecols=[z_component_idx],names=["z"],engine='python')
    M1_df = M1_df.append(data.T)
    idx += segment_skip_idx
```

This results in something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07gni.png). I assume the behaviour is due to the lambda function, but I don't know how to fix it, so that it changes the starting row each time based on `idx` (this is what I thought it would do currently).

Comment: indexing might help [x::2] where x the starting row

Answer (score 0):

Your `cond` lambda is wrong. You want to skip rows if `x < idx` or `x % downsampling != 0`. Just write it that way:

```
cond = x < idx or x % downsampling != 0
```

But you should also consider passing `header = False` to avoid processing the first line of each segment as a header.

Comment: Does `read_csv` go through all of the rows by default? I am trying to achieve so that it would check as few rows as possible to save time. 

For example, if I start from the index 1000, I don't want the function check the first 999 rows, just to see that they are not to be included when reading the data.
 
Something that is working:  
`userows = np.arange(idx,idx+segment_length_idx,downsampling)`

`data = pd.read_csv(filename, skiprows=lambda x: x not in userows, nrows = segment_length_idx/downsampling,usecols=[z_component_idx],names=["z"],engine='python')`
```

But this is very slow